# The exclamation mark in Debug Mode of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Now I am Debuging a project. Actally there are 2 projects using Remoting, which is server, and another is Client. In Sever project, I set some break ponits in the code. And when I start the sever, I find these break ponits are with exclamation marks. What do they really mean? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What do you see if you hover the mouse over it?

Comment: What does it mean by "this point will not be hit"? I find the Debugger will still stop at this line at this breakponit.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever . First thank you for your answer. I have read some articles about .pdb, which is also called symbol files. Actually the debug info is stored in this file, which is a mapping between .cs file and .dll file. You said that, During early startup of a system, it will tend to give false warnings. Can I think that the Debugger doesn't find the corresponding location in dll for this line of code in .cs file. But it actually exists in .pdb, just not loaded into Debugger. While the entire application debug info is loaded from pdb, so the circle will be filled with color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause (and the information usually included in the tooltip for it) is that the breakpoint will not (currently) be hit. This might be caused because, for instance, the assembly that the code resides in has not (yet) been loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your info. I saw the message from the tooltip. What does it mean by "this point will not be hit"? I find the Debugger will still stop at this line at this breakponit.

Comment: @RobinSun - Between when you observe the warning and actually hitting the breakpoint, something is causing the assembly to be loaded (at the same time, the warning will disappear and the circle will become filled with colour). During early startup of a system, it will tend to give false warnings. But if, so far as you're concerned, the entire application is loaded and running and you still see that message, it would be an indicator for you to investigate why that code isn't being loaded.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever .  First thank you for your answer. I have read some articles about .pdb, which is also called symbol files. Actually the debug info is stored in this file, which is a mapping between .cs file and .dll file. You said that, During early startup of a system, it will tend to give false warnings. Can I think that the Debugger doesn't find the corresponding location in dll for this line of code in .cs file. But it actually exists in .pdb, just not loaded into Debugger. While the entire application debug info is loaded from pdb, so the circle will be filled with color.